# How to load HTML5 Canvas game before starting?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, canvas, load

I've made a game in HTML5 Canvas Cordova. It works fine and all, but instances such as "Jump" causes a slight lag the first time, then works fine the second time. I assume it has something to do with the new animation images "loads as it goes". Is there a way to load everything from the start (e.g loading screen) before the game starts?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are third party tools that allow you to do this, I've used [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) in the past and been fairly pleased with it. It has a call called `load` that allows you to pull in assets, and then provides a callback that is invoked when all assets have been loaded.

So, a simple case might look like this:

```
Modernizr.load([
    {
        load: [ 'preload!scripts/myscript1.js', 'images!image/myimage.jpeg' ],
        complete: function () {
            console.log('Everything is loaded!');
            initMyThing();
        }
    }
]);
```

You might run a loading screen script immediately (something trivial to load), and then in the `complete` function here destroy the loading screen and start up your game.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know Cordova but I made a [HTML5 game](http://www.benjaminpageaud.fr/projets/sokoban/bin/game.html) (but with DOM, not Canvas) a few months ago, I used AJAX calls to load all the files I wanted.

1) Server side :
`A script which create a JSON List containing all URLs of the files needed`

So a list like ['/assets/img1.png', '/assets/sound.mp3', ...]

2)a) Client Side : 
`AJAX calls the server script`

2)b) 
`Once the list is received make a GET request for each URL of the list`

You can track the loading by storing the list length and incrementing it each time you received a file, when `currentFileCount == totalFileCount`, the donwload is finished, and you can initialise your game.

Since the files obtained by GET are cached by your browser, the next time you'll want to load the game, your browser will first check in the cache if the file is present and if it is not, it will make the request.

(The file is a bit long for StackOverflow but you can check the [LoadingManager](http://www.benjaminpageaud.fr/projets/sokoban/bin/scripts/LoadingManager.js) I have created which also tracks the progression of each file, comments in French, sorry).

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
function init()
{
    // load stuff here - page has loaded
    // loop through images using an array and don't call the rest of the functions until they have all loaded
}
// browsers with modern versions
if (window.addEventListener)
{
    window.addEventListener("load", init);
}
// other browsers / earlier versions like Internet Explorer pre- 11
else if (window.attachEvent)
{
    window.attachEvent("load", init);
}
```

It's important to note that you can do window.onload or use a plugin, but

Answer (score 0):

I want to load my images before starting the game and here is my code

```js
var images = [];
for (let imageNumber = 0; imageNumber < (rowsNumber * colsNumber) / 2; imageNumber++) {
    image = new Image();
    image.src = './assets/' + imageNumber + '.png';
    images[imageNumber] = image;

}
```

Comment: you can put your assets in array this way it will load before the page